# How to identify the name of the control when clicked

Tags: vb.net, controls

I am adding controls programatically but the problem is I want to show the name of the created controls when clicked.

I can't seem to handle a `Control.MouseDown` over those created controls when they are programatically created.

Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question to show what you have tried. It may be as simple as using `DirectCast(sender, Control)` to convert `sender` from an `Object` to a `Control`.

Comment: You've mentioned two separate issues there, so you should have posted two separate questions.  Also, you haven't shown any code for either issue so either your question is incomplete or, if you have no code, premature.  We're here to help with specific code issues.

Comment: That is because as what I have said on the first paragraph, I want to add a MouseDown handle on the controls that I have programatically created, I searched it all over the internet and found no luck at all so I asked it here.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Questions without code illustrating the problem get closed, downvoted and/or deleted

Comment: @Plutonix, S.O. confuses me.... if you add no code you get basted.. if you DO add code you still get basted for not posting to the code-review page.... I think the question is clear enough... he just had no clue how to ask since he didn't know where he was headed. See my answer.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.***  Its been that way for a long, long time. Code not only clarifies the exact issue, but the OP's skill level.  Its not a good question, it shows no effort, and there are gobs of dupes here already for both issues raised.  Referrals to CR are based on the question - code that works but needs to be faster/better.  Most suggestions to migrate are not correct

Comment: @Plutonix, yes I agree with you, it just seems such a large gray area of what's a question and what's code review. In this particular instance, it is apparent the questioner knows enough to add controls to a form, no simple task in itself, and a little about how events work.. kind of. He is just was not aware of how controls and events are CONNECTED. No amount of code here would have helped with that question in my opinion.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with generic questions, in my opinion, it just gets difficult when you cannot properly ask the question without knowing the answer.... if you get my gist.

Comment: If you add a control dynamically, it doesnt take a Brain Scientist to conclude you did something wrong or missed something.  The next step is to do research.  Lots of research if you are a novice.  Some of the 30,000 related articles on MSDN would be a start.  *Then* if it doesnt work right you post on SO along with the code you are trying to fix.  Posting to SO is supposed to be the *last* resort, not the first thing you do when you get stuck.  The post doesnt show any effort and doesnt even ask a question.  Y

Answer (score 0):

That is because, when you add controls in code, you also need to **specifically add event handlers** to your form for each event you want to handle for that control...

Include code like this where you add the control.

```
AddHandler MyControl1.MouseDown, AddressOf MyControl_MouseDown
```

The handler routine **MUST follow the same argument structure** as the usual event... minus the Handles part.

```
Private Sub MyControl_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)

    ' YOUR HANDLING CODE
End Sub
```

If you REALLY need the name at that point, use the .Name property of the sender object.

**Note:** You can add the same handler routine to multiple controls if you have common code. If you do, use the Sender object to clarify which control was triggered in the handler.

If you remove a control later, remember to remove the handlers..

```
RemoveHandler MyControl1.MouseDown
```

---

**ALTERNATIVE METHOD**

If the maximum number of controls you plan on adding is known, then you can add place-holders for them at the top of your form code class...

```
WithEvents MyControl1 As WhateverItIs
WithEvents MyControl2 As WhateverItIs
WithEvents MyControl3 As WhateverItIs
WithEvents MyControl4 As WhateverItIs
WithEvents MyControl5 As WhateverItIs
WithEvents MyControl6 As WhateverItIs
etc
```

Note that does not actually create the buttons at that point, they will all be Nothing, but it does tell the compiler what to do with events from those objects when they are assigned to actual objects.

Then assign those when you add the actual control...

```
Dim NewControl as WhateverItIs
Me.Controls.add NewControl
MyControl1 = NewControl
```

That way you can add the code for **ALL the control's event types** for each placeholder if you need them.

```
Private Sub MyControl1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyControl1.MouseDown
    ' YOUR HANDLING CODE
End Sub

Private Sub MyControl1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyControl1.MouseUp
    ' YOUR HANDLING CODE
End Sub

'etc
```

If you remove a control later remember, to reset the placeholder to nothing..

```
MyControl1 = Nothing
```

Unfortunately, you can't make an array or list of WithEvents place-holders.

**Note:** This is exactly how Visual Studio builds the form designer for you automatically. Each time you add a control through the studio UI, VS adds all that code automatically.